# ZeroRPC between nodejs and Python running only for the first time

Tags: python, node.js, zeromq, pyzmq, zerorpc

We are trying to call a python module from NodeJS using ZeroRPC.

Nodejs Code:

```
app.get('/topList', function(req, res){
    var zerorpc = require("zerorpc");
    var client = new zerorpc.Client({ timeout: 3000, heartbeatInterval: 300000 });
    console.log('Here');
    client.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4212");
    console.log('And Here');
    client.invoke("toplist", '2015-02-13T05:46:29.800Z', '2015-02-13T08:46:29.800Z', function(error, tlist, more) 
    {
        console.log('And Here also');
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
        } 
        console.log(tlist);
        res.send(tlist);
        client.close();
    });
});
```

Python code:

```
import zerorpc
import logging
import gevent
logging.basicConfig()

class HelloRPC(object):
   def toplist(self, fromtime, tilltime): 
       print 'Python Hello'
       # Doing some some manipulations and placing the result in the variable top_20
       return top_20

 p = HelloRPC()  
 s = zerorpc.Server(p)
 s.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:4212")
 s.run()
```

First we ran the python code to up the server. Next we start the nodejs code.

Now in the browser for the first time if we try for localhost:8080/topList, nodejs issues an request to python, then python program is running and returning the result to nodejs, then in the browser we are able to see the result.

The problem comes if we try for the second time localhost:8080/topList, nodejs not able to invoke the python code. We didn't see 'Python Hello' in python console.

We are not able to fix this scenario. It is only running for the first time, then nodejs not able to invoke python. Is the server is getting closed after runnig first time.

We also tried to use While True or gevent like below. But still same issue.

```
While True:
    p = HelloRPC()  
    s = zerorpc.Server(p)
    s.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:4212")
    s.run()
    #gevent.spawn(s.run)
```

Can anyone will provide some idea to fix this ?

Comment: What is the value of the "more" parameter each time ?. What's the last "message" you see on the console ? ... is "An Here" ?

Comment: Heartbeat on the server and client must be the same. s = zerorpc.Server(p, timeout=300000); But why a crazy value like that?

Comment: We have solved it by removing the line var client = new zerorpc.Client({ timeout: 3000, heartbeatInterval: 300000 }); inside app.get and called it only once in the beginning of code ie.. before app.get.  I will also look out the value for timeout..Thanks everyone..